# Connect SQL DW from Jupyter notebook using pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to pyspark, so can you please suggest how to connect SQL DW from Pyspark using jupyter-notebook. I'm not using HDinsight or DataBricks.

I have setup the pyspark and Jupyter-note book using [this](https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please make sure you have downloaded the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server from here ([Download Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)) and add it to your spark jar libraries path.

Second, it sounds like you setup the pyspark and Jupyter notebook on premise or on local. If that without on Azure cloud, you must add your client ip into your Azure SQL DW firewalls as the figure below, please refer to the section [`Create a server-level firewall rule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/create-data-warehouse-portal#create-a-server-level-firewall-rule) of the offical document `Quickstart: Create and query an Azure SQL data warehouse in the Azure portal` to know more about that.

[image]

Next, you need to find the JDBC connection string of Azure SQL DW as the section [`Sample JDBC connection string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-connection-strings#sample-jdbc-connection-string) of the document `Connection strings for Azure SQL Data Warehouse` said, you should see it from the tabs `Overview` or `SQL databases` on Azure portal.

Then, you can refer to the blog [`PySpark connection with MS SQL Server`](https://blog.hassanmehmood.com/pyspark-connection-with-ms-sql-server/) to try to connect Azure SQL DW via pyspark in your jupyter notebook.

Hope it helps.